# how to use (while) and (try) statements to handle errors of user inputs from one of three choices only

Tags: python, error-handling, while-loop, try-catch, user-input

I'm a beginner in Python and I need to write an interactive code, in which I ask the user which one do you like x, y or z?
and I want to use (while) loop and (try) statement to do so.

I tried the following:

```
q1 = input('Would like to see data of Washington, Chicago or New York? \n')

while q1 == 'Washington'or =='Chicago' or == 'New York'
    try:
        print()
        break
    except:
        print('invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
```

Comment: That’s not how comparison and logical operators work. You need to use `q1` in all three comparisons. You also have the logic inverted. You want to loop while this condition is *not* true.

Comment: Whatever you right inside the try block is usually checked for, if there is any error, and subsequently you write the corresponding error msg in except block

Comment: Actually, there are some more problems with this code. You seem to be still lacking some fundamental concepts of how programming works. You should get a teacher or read a good book or online tutorial. Stack Overflow is not meant to replace that.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I disagree with you. All roads lead to Rome. There are different ways of learning things.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
q1 = input('Would like to see data of Washington, Chicago or New York? \n')

while q1 == 'Washington' or q1 =='Chicago' or q1 == 'New York':
    try:
        print()
        break
    except:
        print('invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
```

You need to repeat `q1` for each conditional statement...

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
while true:
    q1 = input('Would like to see data of Washington, Chicago or New York? \n')
    if q1 not in [ 'Washington', 'Chicago', 'New York' ]:
        print('invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit the user's input in some choices it is better to put the choices together in a list then compare the input to them as follows:

```
choices = ['Washington', 'Chicago', 'New York']
q1 = input("Would like to see data of Washington, Chicago or New York? \n")
while q1 not in choices:
    print('invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
    q1 = input()
```

so later on if you want to add more choices you can do it easily by modifying the choices variable.
This code will block in the while loop until the user input is one of the choices. However, the user input must be exactly (case sensitive) as on of the choices (i.e. chicago won't work, it should be Chicago with capital 'c').

My advise (if you don't mind for the exact case sensitive name) is to make the choices all small letter like this:

```
choices = ['washington', 'chicago', 'new york']
```

then compare the user input (lowercased) to the choices as follows:

```
while q1.lower() not in choices:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution -1

If you want to achieve continues loop until user enters incorrect value, try below code.

```
while flag:
    q1 = input('Would like to see data of Washington, Chicago or New York? \n')
    try:
        if q1 in [ 'Washington', 'Chicago', 'New York' ]:
            print('your result is: ' + q1)
        else:
            flag=0
            print('Invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
            break
    except:
        flag=0
        print('Invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
        break
```

Solution - 2

We can achieve this by using if-else, however if you want to use while loop then try below code.

Editted code

```
q1 = input('Would like to see data of Washington, Chicago or New York? \n')
flag = 0;
while (q1 == 'Washington' or q1 =='Chicago' or q1 == 'New York'):
    try:
        flag = 1
        break
    except:
        print('invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
        
if(flag):
    print('your result is: ' + q1)
else:
    print('Invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
```

Please try this code:

**your code is correct but just need to add q1 for all cases in while condition**

```
q1 = input('Would like to see data of Washington, Chicago or New York? \n')

while (q1 == 'Washington' or q1 =='Chicago' or q1 == 'New York'):
    try:
        print('your result is: ' + q1)
        break
    except:
        print('invalid input, please select a name of a city!')
```

Comment: i tried it, when i input a non-valid value, it continue normally and doesn't show a message

Comment: in that case we need to modify using if-else. try this code: